# Firestore rules 'Simulated read allowed' but fails in browser

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My security rules are super simple. I have two collections - `riders` and `races`:

- `riders`: can only be read from or written to when the user is signed in
- `races`: can be read from by unauthenticated user; written to when user is signed in.

```js
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {    
    // restrict read/write on all to authenticated
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
      
      // then allow collection read if match
      match /races/{id} {
        allow read, list: if true;
      } 
      
    }
  }  
}
```

These rules allow what appears to be the correct setup using the Firebase consoles `Rules Playground` but in the browser auth users behave as expected but the unauthed users are returned an error when making a call for a race:

```sh
core.js:6456 ERROR FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at new e (prebuilt-47338342-439a2133.js:188)
    at prebuilt-47338342-439a2133.js:10415
    at prebuilt-47338342-439a2133.js:10416
    at e.onMessage (prebuilt-47338342-439a2133.js:10438)
    at prebuilt-47338342-439a2133.js:10355
    at prebuilt-47338342-439a2133.js:10386
    at prebuilt-47338342-439a2133.js:15146
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:372)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:134)
    at zone.js:1276
```

```js
// service call

this.racesCollection = this.firestore.collection<Race>('races');

this.racesCollection
      .doc(id)
      .valueChanges()
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe((response: any) => {
        console.log('=== APP SERVICE emits race ===', response);
        this.race.next(response);
      });
```

I've tried rewriting the rules but cannot seem to find my way around this one. Any help or ideas appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write your security rules in such a way they [overlap](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure?authuser=1#overlapping_match_statements):

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {    
    // restrict read/write on all to authenticated
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;      
    }

    // then allow read for the races collection for all users
    match /races/{id} {
      allow read, list: if true;
    } 

  }  
}
```

In addition, note that `list` is a "sub-case" of `read`, so you might remove the `list` rule, i.e. just do `allow read: if true;`.

---

BTW, the simulator does correctly show that your rules do not allow reading a document in the `races` collection if you are not authenticated.